# how to select button by matching text inside a span

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I want to disable a button which comes up in the dialog based on a condition. The problem is how do i access the button since its dynamically generated via the dialog ?

Generated html code in the dialog:

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Save</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume there was a typo in your code and you didnt mean to close the opening span tag, so your code is

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Save</span>
</button>
```

Then you can change the word Save in the next line to whatever text is in the button you want to hide

```
$("button span:contains('Save')").parent().attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

for dynamic generation of DOM u can use `.live()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery to match on attributes:

```
$('button[role=button]').attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span:contains('Save')").parent().attr("disabled", true);
```